# Python List to dictionary conversion

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a list structured like:

```
content =   [
       {
         "a" : "b",
         "c" : "d",
       },
       {
          "e" : "f",
          "g: : "h",
       }
   ]
```

There are some null values in the dictionary inside there and i want to filter them in my template. That is the main purpose but for now i want to convert this lists to dictionary as im performing filter in such way:

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in content.items() if v is None)
```

And as expected it gives me an attribute error.

Comment: can you paste your error trace.

Comment: list' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content` is a list. Use nested loops.

```
dict((k, v) for d in content for k, v in d.items() if v is None)
```

Comment: hey thanks, but it gives me an error, `global name 'd' is not defined`

Comment: Got the loops backwards.